# Angular blocks svg xmlns as $sce:insecurl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, angularjs-material

I am building an app in Angular Material and have an md-icon structured as follows:

```
<md-icon class="ic1" md-svg-src='data:image/svg+xml,
  <svg xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <ellipse ry="16" rx="16" id="svg_1" cy="16" cx="16" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#ff0000"/>                                    
  </svg>' class="s32">
</md-icon>
```

But it can't load as Angular blocks the call to `https://www.w3.org/2000/svg` (I've tried both HTTP and HTTPS) and throws a $sce:insecurl error:

[image: Error description]

As the docs suggest, I tried adding the url to the SCE whitelist:

```
app.config(function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', 'https://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'https://*.w3.org/**'])
})
```

But it had no effect.

How can I make it work?

Please note that I have simplified the HTML to show only relevant stuff, in reality I change the fill color dynamically based on a variable so I would rather not save each SVG as a file if I can get this dynamic version to work.

Comment: Note: Although that string looks like a URL, it isn't a real one.  It is just a constant value for `xmlns` that means "this is an SVG".  Changing it to `https` would technically break it.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thanks, that's good to know. Note that it doesn't work with http either though, and Angular blocks it as if it was a URL, for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you are generating that SVG string at runtime, rather than hardcoding it as above? Otherwise you wouldn't be able to change the fill colour.

Ie. so something like:

```
 md-svg-src='{{generateIcon()}} ...
```

Is that correct?

If that's the case, then have you tried Base64 encoding the SVG?

```
generateIcon() {
  svgStr = "whatever";
  return "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + base64(svgStr);
}
```

Perhaps there is a better Angular way to solve this. But this might be a possible workaround.

Comment: Not exactly, the SVG itself is as it looks in the answer, the only difference is that the "fill" property is something like fill="{{ (var1 === 'red') ? '#ff0000' : '#0000ff' }}" instead of plain color. I developed the page on CodePen before inserting it in my main app and it worked fine, so it can't be a problem with the SVG itself

Comment: I had to create a function to do this, but converting the content do base64 like you said fixed the issue. Thank you!